# PIC capture interrupt not triggering at 0.65v

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupts, pic, microchip

I connected pulse input to CCP1 pin( capture1 pin), maximum and minimum volt of pulse is 2.5v and 0.65v

interrupt setted on falling edge

problem is, interrupt not triggering at 0.65v

but when I connect ground to CCP1 pin its triggering.

so is it normal that CCP1 requires 0v/Vss not 0.6v?

Microcontroller: pic16f876A

```
void timer1Int(){
T1CKPS1 = 1;    // 11 = 1:8 Prescale value
T1CKPS0 = 1;
T1OSCEN = 0;    // Oscillator is shut off
TMR1CS = 0;     // input clock to the timer is F OSC/4,   T1SYNC has no effect    
TMR1ON = 1;     // Enables Timer1
TMR1IE = 1;
TMR1 = 0;

//CCPx Mode Select byte
CCP1CON = 0x04;  //  Capture mode, every falling edge
CCPR1 = 0;
CCP1IE = 1;     //  Enables the CCP1 interrupt   
}
```

[CIRICUIT DIAGRAM, this never goes 0v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARok.jpg)

Comment: Show your Code, please!

Comment: I guess you need a pull-down resistor as well.

Comment: How is this ("Is it normal that CCP1 requires 0v/Vss not 0.6v?") a *programming question*?

Comment: EEs descriptiojn says: "We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. ... We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a **schematic**, links to pertinent datasheets or **some source code** in them"

Comment: This information is usually found in the datasheet "electrical characteristics" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I connected pulse input to CCP1 pin( capture1 pin), maximum and
>   minimum volt of pulse is 2.5v and 0.65v

The CCP1 input has a Schmitt-trigger on it, which requires a voltage swing of at least 0.2Vdd to 0.8Vdd (= 1V to 4V when Vdd is 5V). If your signal is only going up to 2.5V then the CCP1 signal will stick low and input pulses will be ignored.

[image]

Your circuit diagram shows a PC817 optocoupler with 3.3k pull-up resistor. If being driven properly it *should* be producing ~0.2V to 5V. You should find out what is causing the reduced voltage swing and correct it.